# ASP GridView double click event only when edit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I having a Gridview where I want to go in edit mode when double click happens:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Edit$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        }
```

And it works fine but when I#m already in edit mode and double click again into the TextBox I get following error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Is there a way to catch this, so it doesn't show the erro above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` check on `Page_Load` event, give unique IDs for every item template column controls inside the grid (better to show gridview ASPX markup and full page code behind for clarity).

Comment: EnableEventValidation = "false" did it. I don't know if there are some security issues? But for an Intranet Application it maybe ok....